# How to make ListViewItem share the same height and scale automatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListView` in a `Grid` inside a `MainWindow`, and it has defined a `DateTemplate` inside of the `ItemTemplate`, which includes a `TextBlock`, each `TextBlock` has a different length of text, some are long, and some short.

The application needs to fit different screen resolutions, that is, the `FontSize` of each `TextBlock` needs to be autoscaled accordingly.

So I wrap the `TextBlock` with a `ViewBox`, but the problem is, the short text will get a bigger `FontSize` than the long text, I want all `TextBlock`'s can share the same `FontSize` and can autoscale to fit different screen size and resolution, any idea?

My ListView is as below:

```
<ListView x:Name="specs" Margin="10 15 10 15" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Kaiti Regular"/>
            </Viewbox>

         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared size group to force the textblocks all to have the same width as the widest one, which in turn will force the Viewboxes to scale identically.

The key things here are `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` on the ListView, and putting the content of the ViewBox in a grid column with `SharedSizeGroup="SomeArbitraryString"`. Under a given parent that's a shared size scope, all the grid columns in a particular named shared size group will have the same width as the widest one (and the same for grid rows and height).

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="specs" 
    Margin="10 15 10 15" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Words}"
    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
    >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="Text" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock 
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Text="{Binding}" 
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                        FontFamily="Kaiti Regular"
                        />
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I'm not convinced this will resolve the entire issue, but it'll get you another step along. And in general, it's a wonderfully useful tool for DataTemplate layout in ItemsControls.